# Dichotomy for global existence or blow up for solutions of evolution problems.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, dynamical-systems

Consider the problem (Nonlinear Schrödinger equation)
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
      iu_t + \Delta u\mp u|u|^{\alpha}=0\\
      u(0) =\varphi\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N), \\
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
where $N\geq 3$ and $0<\alpha<\frac{4}{N}$.

I consider solution in the strong sense, i.e. $u(t,x)\in C^0([0,T],H^1(\mathbb{R}^N))$ such that

\begin{equation}
u(t)= e^{it\Delta}\varphi \pm i\int_0^t e^{i(t-s)\Delta}u|u|^{\alpha}(s)ds,
\end{equation}

where $T=T\left(\|\varphi\|_{H^1}\right)$. And $e^{it\Delta}\varphi(x)$ is the solution of the linear Schrödinger equation:

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
      iu_t + \Delta u=0\\
      u(0) =\varphi\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N). \\
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

I can prove that such solution exist.

I know that there exist the following dichotomy:

1) $T=+\infty$

2)$T<\infty$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow T^{-}} \|u(t)\|_{H^1}=+\infty.$

I would like to know how to prove this dichotomy.

Maybe it is a more general fact, but in order to not make mistakes I preferred to enunciate the statement in my particular case.

Thank you for your help...